# How to perform a textchanged event in vb.net datagrid textboxes

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have a datagrid view in my vb.net windows form. I have to load values to some of the textboxes depending on the first column of the datagrid.
For example : if i type a name of the person in first datagrid view column, then the second column should automatically load with that persons mobile number. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `OnCellValueChanged`, the problem with this is that it doesn't fire until you leave editing a cell.